# Magento 2 Hide "Ship TO"

Tags: shipping, stores

Based on a Store Pickup Module.
How can I hide the "SHIP TO" sidebar when the customer  pick this supplier ?

Answer (score 1):

You should override layout checkout_index_index.xml and add the code below

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <referenceBlock name="shipping-information" remove="true"/>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me:

In view/frontend/web/js/requireJs add :

```
    },
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information': {
        'MYMODULE/js/view/shipping-information': true
    },
```

IN shipping-information.js :

```
    /*global define*/
    define(
        [
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
        ], function (quote) {
            'use strict';

            return function (target) {
                return target.extend({
                    isVisible: function() {
                        var isVisible = this._super();

                        if (quote.shippingMethod()) {
                            var method = quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code + '_' + quote.shippingMethod().method_code;



                            if (method === 'myModule') {
                                isVisible = false;
console.log('Not visible is HERE');
                            }
                        }

                        return isVisible;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
```